# Add 1 to an array element in C

Tags: c, arrays, element, addition

So, is this correct?

```
void norte( int local[ ] )
{
   local[0]=local[0]+1;
}
```

The objective is to add 1 to the 1st element of the array local[2]

For instance,
 {2,1}---->{3,1}

EDIT:

Comment: Really? Did you even try it to see if it works?

Comment: there is a really easy way to know if it works, compile, execute, print

Comment: I have this big ass code that for some reason gets stuck in a while loop containing this function. I wonder if it this that is failing.

Comment: This is the correct method. I think what @qwrrty and others are responding to is the fact that this doesn't pass the requirement `this question shows research effort`.

Comment: that's what the debugger is for, you can check if it is working or not

Comment: @user3092390 Post the full code with the question, we might be of better help!

Comment: @user3092390 There's nothing wrong with this portion. Perhaps if you make a new question with the rest of the code demonstrating your methodologies you can get a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this works.

Alternatively, you can do `local[0] += 1` or `++local[0]`.

Be sure the pointer you give to your function is valid and points to a int.

Answer (score 1):

Try your code before posting a problem.

Yes, your code will work, but you also could use this

```
local[0]++;
```

And it's much cleaner